# “The volume does not contain a recognized file system” on C: Drive, Can I Recover Data?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, hardware-failure

Last night my desktop started to slow down and I shut it down; the machine runs Windows 10 and I believe it was attempting an update as I've noticed similar performance issues like that when Windows 10 is attempting an update on other machines. The machine will not boot up now. I made a number of attempts to get the machine going again but was left with the opinion that the OS was corrupted. I created a recovery disk and when it loaded I attempted to access the C: drive but was met with the error: `The volume does not contain a recognized file system`. I can access the other hard drive. I'm presuming either the OS is corrupted or that the hard drive failed. I'd hate to think the hard drive failed as it is an SSD drive, 512GB; but I suppose it's a potential. If the hard drive is still viable I'd like to reinstall the OS but I can't even access the hard drive to get data off of it. Is this possible? My searches online have been met with a lot of faux articles for companies selling data recovery tools. Is there a way to recover the data? Or even get the system running again?

Comment: You might consider running `chkdsk /x /r /f c:` to fix the file system if it is repairable to start I suppose.

Comment: **Before** you try to repair the file system, *image* the SSD as best you can, e.g. using a rescue disk or Live Linux UB device. Repair may be possible, but it might destroy data.

Comment: In some cases using a Live Linux USB drive - you can access the data. Mount it as read only and usually quite useful to get access to it. Or use software like TestDisk (also often available in linux live USB)

Comment: The disk might be BitLocker encrypted. What kind of recovery disk did you create? Are you booting a windows setup disk and entering recovery mode? I’m pretty sure it will prompt you for a BitLocker key.

Comment: Please go into your BIOS setup -> boot section -> windows boot manager,  
 change UEFI for Legacy then restart your laptop for test. Also please remember to try bootrec command to fix the boot file.

Comment: If the disk is physically readable it's likely that at least some data can be recovered.  Photorec can look at the raw disk and try pull stuff out, but it's not great. The ideal is to try and reair the filesystem to make it readable - the details of which depends on the filesystem and type of corruption.

Comment: Thanks all, I have run `chkdsk` and `bootrec`, and neither have resolved the issue. `chkdsk` noted numerous issues. The results reinforce to me that the disk has failed.